# Can't run identical .py file under Apache

Tags: python, apache-httpd

I set up Apache webserver on my Pi.
I got all my permissions set and was able to run a "hello world" python program.

The JavaScript:

```
function hellowWorld(){          
     $.ajax({               
            url: "cgi/helloworld.py",           
            dataType: "json",       
            type: "post",           
            error: ajaxError,           
            success: function(json){  
                    console.log(json.msg);
            }
     });        
}
```

The python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import cgi

header=0

def hw():
        jData={
            "msg":"hello world"
        }
        return ("Content-type: application/json\r\n\r\n"+json.dumps(jData)) 
        

print( hw() )
```

Then, I literally copied helloworld.py to a new file called defaults.py and tested it, but I get an error 500.

```
function loadDefaults(){             
     $.ajax({               
            url: "cgi/defaults.py",             
            dataType: "json",       
            type: "post",           
            error: ajaxError,           
            success: function(json){                        
                    console.log(json.msg);
            }
     });        
}
```

As far as I can tell, these 2 .py files have exactly the same permissions.

```
264069 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 208 Sep 27 11:00 defaults.py
264068 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 193 Sep 27 11:00 helloworld.py
```

Why will one run but not the other?

Comment: You said you copied the file to defaults.py and changed permissions; did you modify the file at all? The file sizes differ according to the `ls` output

Comment: Run `diff helloworld.py defaults.py` to check if there are and what are the differences between the two files.

Comment: `diff helloworld.py defaults.py`
returns **1,15c1,15** before listing the 2 files. I'm not sure what that means.
If there are any differences, it might be a space or something. I can run both from the command line.

Comment: I re-copied using `sudo cp -rp helloworld.py defaults.py` and that worked so somehow I was missing a permission or something, but wouldn't `ls -li` tell me that?

Comment: ls-li do tells you that file have different size, so are different, maybe defaults.py have syntax errors?

Comment: Not a syntax error because it runs after I specifically copy using **-rp**.  I obviously missed something in the permissions, but I don't understand what.